# What to be done if company does not provide Form 16

Tags: income-tax, india

I am asking to my company for Form 16 for last 2 months. They didn't give though the due date passes.

When I ask, they keep giving saying we will send you soon.

I worked from `13 August 2014 to 5th August 2015` in that company, now working with different company. My tax was being deducted directly from salary. When I left, they gave last 3 months salary slip.

I my friends are done with IT return, but still I have not received form 16.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do 2 things;

**File Returns:**
You should already know your income and the tax deducted every year. You can long into the [income tax website](https://nriservices.tdscpc.gov.in/nriapp/login.xhtml) and see your tax credits [Form 26AS], just to make sure your employer has credited the tax to Govt. Calculate your tax, deduction and file the returns.

**File a complaint:**
An employer has to provide a TRACES generated Form 16 to the employee by 31-may. Failure to do so attracts penalty. You can provide a written complaint to the local IT ward office giving out the details. **Edit** For more info see [Section 4.6](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Communications/Circular/Circular17_2014.pdf)

Comment: thanks for this info. Can you please point me to link for 2nd point? It will help me to show my employer

Comment: @user123 see the edit.